# Error when trying to install StackImpact library in GO

Tags: go

I'm getting the below errors when trying to install StackImpact in GO. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tnx..

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.
C:\Users\leonardo>go get github.com/stackimpact/stackimpact-go
# github.com/stackimpact/stackimpact-go/internal
C:\gowork\src\github.com\stackimpact\stackimpact-go\internal\process_reporter.go
:96: undefined: syscall.Getrusage
C:\gowork\src\github.com\stackimpact\stackimpact-go\internal\process_reporter.go
:102: rusage.Utime undefined (type *syscall.Rusage has no field or method Utime)
C:\gowork\src\github.com\stackimpact\stackimpact-go\internal\process_reporter.go
:103: rusage.Utime undefined (type *syscall.Rusage has no field or method Utime)
C:\gowork\src\github.com\stackimpact\stackimpact-go\internal\process_reporter.go
:104: rusage.Stime undefined (type *syscall.Rusage has no field or method Stime)
C:\gowork\src\github.com\stackimpact\stackimpact-go\internal\process_reporter.go
:105: rusage.Stime undefined (type *syscall.Rusage has no field or method Stime)
C:\gowork\src\github.com\stackimpact\stackimpact-go\internal\process_reporter.go
:112: undefined: syscall.Getrusage
C:\gowork\src\github.com\stackimpact\stackimpact-go\internal\process_reporter.go
:117: rusage.Maxrss undefined (type *syscall.Rusage has no field or method Maxrs
s)
C:\Users\leonardo>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compile a code that's meant for linux in Windows. syscall.Getrusage is a linux system call.

https://golang.org/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go?s=13296:13347#L546

Answer (score 0):

Windows is supported starting from agent version [1.2.2](https://github.com/stackimpact/stackimpact-go).